# Oracle Lock Table - Syntax Error for 'Table'

Tags: oracle, plsql, locking

I have created a function for user to insert an entry into a table. Previously user supply the id for the next insert. Now Management wants my function to supply the next id. (ID is a combination of 'AC' and 6 digits So my function has to get the max of id and add one to it.) Management wants no race condition, so I use `lock table`. However there is a 'Syntax error' for `Table`. Why?

[image: Syntax error for table]

If I compile, there is no error message. (*To all, yes, it compiles.*) When I test in Oracle SQL Developer (I have two instances running, and select 'Run...' to test.), I see both instances return the same number (v_NextAccessCode).

From [Database SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm), I know that the table must be in same schema. Yes I have that. Both table and function are in the same schema. (The function is in my own package.)

I have the following: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome. ;)

```
FUNCTION CreateAccessCode(
    i_AccessType         IN  VARCHAR2,
    i_Description        IN  VARCHAR2,
    ...
    errMsg               OUT VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
    v_NextAccessCode             NUMBER;
    v_NextACString               VARCHAR2(8);
    v_count                      NUMBER;
    E_INUSE                      EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    -- Lock table manually
    LOCK TABLE CMS_ACCESS_CODES 
    IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;

    SELECT TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(MAX(ACCESS_CODE), 3, LENGTH(MAX(ACCESS_CODE)) - 2) + 1)
    INTO v_NextAccessCode
    FROM CMS_ACCESS_CODES;

    v_NextACString := 'AC' || v_NextAccessCode;

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_count
    FROM CMS_ACCESS_CODES 
    WHERE ACCESS_CODE = v_NextACString;

    IF v_count > 0 THEN
        errMsg := 'Another user may be creating an access code now. '
                    || 'Please try again later.';
        RAISE E_INUSE;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO CMS_ACCESS_CODES (ACCESS_CODE, ACCESS_TYPE, DESCRIPTION)
    VALUES (v_NextACString, i_AccessType, i_Description);

    -- Release lock
    COMMIT;

    RETURN v_NextAccessCode;
```

[**Edit**] Dear all, strange as it is, there is **syntax error** reported by my SQL Developer. Before I add the `LOCK TABLE`, the Code Outline window shows the create function name.

[image: Code Outline]

And while typing `LOCK TABLE`, I have:

[image: Code Outline for <code>LOCK TABLE</code>]

Please note the ID is a combination of 'AC' and 6 digits. So my function has to get the maximum ID and add one to it.

Version of my SQL Developer is 4.2.0.17.089 Build 17.089.1709. Just check the latest is Version 17.3.1.279.0537, Updated October 17, 2017. (From [SQL Developer Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html))

I don't know what else I can show you to convince you that I see syntax error but compiles ok. But when I test, the `LOCK TABLE` is not performing what I expect.
[**/Edit**]

Comment: Code looks ok. Please provide testscripts and output, including error messages.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message you get?

Comment: Dear both, right after I type in `TABLE` in `LOCK TABLE`, a line appears under it saying there is syntax error. How to resolve it?  As for testing it out, I just open up two instances of SQL Developer and select `Run...` the function. In Log Window (View -> Log) of both, both returns the same number. It looks like the lock table is not doing its job. If it does, the two should return different number (because the second one in execution should wait to get a hold on the table).

Comment: You've got a contradiction there

1) you say there is a syntax error
2) you say when you run the function ...

One of your statements suggests the function does not compile, the other suggests that it does.

You need to give some *precision* here.

Comment: "Management wants no race condition". The only reason you might get a race condition in the first place is because you are not using a sequence to generate the number. Presumably this is due either to the pointless prepending of `'AC'` to the id or a misguided quest to have a "gapless" series.

Comment: If you can't compile the code how can you be running it? The code **as you have posted it** compiles (minus the ellipsis) so whatever compilation error you have appears in a different version of the code from the one posted here.

Comment: If you compile there is no error message, therefore there is no syntax error. SQL Developer is just erroneously flagging something it thinks is an error. If you aren’t using the current versionthen upgrade; if it still does it then report it as a (minor) bug...? Also, when testing, are you running two separate instances of SQL Developer or just using two worksheets in one instance, with a shared connection?

Comment: SQL Developer 17.3.1 also highlights the word `TABLE` with a red underline. It's still wrong, and presumably a bug  in the client. It is not a problem with the database or your code. If you aren't seeing the behaviour you want then that is nothing to do with that misleading red line. (You can report a bug against SQL Developer via My Oracle Support; there's also a forum for it, and its developers hang out here sometimes...)

Comment: Dear all, I have updated my post. Connor: Yes my code has syntax error, but compiles. APC: The 'AC' is required. It is part of ID ('AC' + 6 digits). Originally, user can input any number, so you are right, there is no sequence to generate number initially. Alex: Sorry what is shared connection? I just open up two SQL Developer and have not changed anything about connection setting. (I am from SQL Developer background. Pardon me if I don't know much Oracle.)